# Moverse entre inputs mediante Onkeyup

Tags: javascript

Si tengo varios input que con el onkeyup pasa automaticamente a otro ¿cómo hago para que al borrar regresa automaticamente al input anterior?

Aquí un ejemplo varios input que con el onkeyup pasa automaticamente a otro ¿cómo hago para que al borrar regresa automaticamente al input anterior?

```
<input type="text" name="da" maxlength="1" max="9" min="0" required 
    onkeyup="if (this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) input2.focus()"  autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" id="input2" name="db" maxlength="1" max="9" min="0" required 
    onkeyup="if (this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) input3.focus()" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" id="input3" name="dc" maxlength="1" max="9" min="0" required 
    onkeyup="if (this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) input4.focus()" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente, comprueba la longitud del contenido del input, si después del keyup la longitud es 0, le pasas el foco al anterior. Te dejo el ejemplo.

```html
<input type="text" id = "input1" name="da" maxlength="1" max="9" min="0" required 
    onkeyup="if (this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) input2.focus()"  autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" id="input2" name="db" maxlength="1" max="9" min="0" required 
    onkeyup="if (this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) input3.focus(); if (this.value.length == 0) input1.focus();" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" id="input3" name="dc" maxlength="1" max="9" min="0" required 
    onkeyup="if (this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) input4.focus(); if (this.value.length == 0) input2.focus();" autocomplete="off">
```